# Can I rely on template type?

Tags: c++, templates

I am looking into working code from Game AI by example book and there is a part I do not understand.

There is

```
template <class node_type, class edge_type>   
class SparseGraph                                 
{ ... };
```

and

```
int SparseGraph<node_type, edge_type>::AddNode(node_type node)
{
  if (node.Index() < (int)m_Nodes.size())
...
}
```

How can be `node.Index()`called?

There also is class

```
class GraphNode
{  
public:
...   
  int  Index()const{return m_iIndex;}
....
};
```

and graph is created with this class

```
typedef SparseGraph<GraphNode, GraphEdge> NavGraph;
NavGraph * m_pGraph;
```

so I understand what `node.Index()` does, BUT
how can I call `node.Index()` while there is no guarantee that `node_type` is `GraphNode`.

what if `node_type` is not `GraphNode`??

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: I think you need to get a good book that tells you how templates work. "Duck typing" is the keyword.

Comment: @Xeo : Or "parametric polymorphism" if you don't want to read a bunch of blog posts written by people only familiar with dynamic programming languages. :-P

Comment: @ildjarn: But duck typing sounds nicer. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `node_type` is not GraphNode, then your compiler will smack you and throw an error. However, if your class depends on the `Index` function, then you should document it as a requirement and any replacement for GraphNode must provide it, probably with some expected semantics.

Comment: Ok, so what is the purpose to use templates for this? I can do it with base class GraphNode and polymorphism, can't I?

Comment: @relaxxx: The point of using a template is that you can use it with any type that provides the required functions and semantics- it doesn't have to inherit from or be related to `GraphNode` in any way.

Answer (score 3):

[Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

There is also a convenient feature in C++ called [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error) that will remove a template from the considered candidates if an expression dependent on the type would not compile with the particular concrete type.

A way of restricting the types accepted as template parameters based on supported operations, i.e. Concepts, was originally planned for C++0x but scrapped due to committee disagreement on its design. You can still find early implementations in some forks of GCC and Boost also has a concepts library. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm).

Answer (score 2):

C++ template functions are instantiated at point of use. i.e., it will paste in the types you specify *when* you specify them, and not sooner. At that point, if the type you specify does not have an `Index` member function, the compilation will fail.